# Unreal engine how do I change the visual studio version without having loaded up a project?

Tags: unreal-4, unreal, visual-studio

I get an error which I mentioned in a previous post. I did a little more research on this error and found out that I need to use an up-to-date visual studio. I think that I might need to change the visual studio version from the config. I have both visual studio 2017 and 2013 on my computer.

Answer (score 1):

to anyone else who has been searching for the answer of how to switch vis studio version without opening project, you must change the selected version in both the DefaultEditor and DefaultEditorSettings files located in the config folder.

will look like this

[/Script/SourceCodeAccess.SourceCodeAccessSettings]
PreferredAccessor=VisualStudio[your desired version number]

in my case I had to switch from a 2019 to 2017 so it looks like this

[/Script/SourceCodeAccess.SourceCodeAccessSettings]
PreferredAccessor=VisualStudio2017

Answer (score 0):

4.15 uses only VS2015+. Easiest solution is to uninstall 2013. Otherwise, just open the game solution in 2017 and compile it. It's unclear what you mean by "without having loaded the project".